# How to force imported child component to re-render without access to the child component's code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux, react-hooks

I have imported someone else's metronome component which uses a startBpm prop to automatically render the metronome at a certain tempo. Now I imported that into its parent: a song component which should render the metronome with a startbpm prop of the song's tempo. On the initial render it works. However, when I change the song (and with it the tempo) the metronome stays at the original start bpm which leads to me to believe it is not re-rendering, even though it is ostensibly receiving the new tempo as a prop. The rest of the song detail component re-renders without issue. So my question is - how do I force this imported component to re-render with the new prop without access to its actual code?

Comment: Set a different key

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!